# Deserializing response with an array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Im using json.net and I have problem deserializing json response from server I dont know what data type should I use for two properties `errors` and `data`.

Is there a way how to exclude others atributes but these two? The server is returning a lot of data Im not interested in.

Also I made data types in class `Data` nullable because when values is unknown server returns null is it right way to solve this problem?

```
class DataFormat
{
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Object Errors { get; set; }

    ...

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }    
}

class Data
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double? Open { get; set; }
    public double? High { get; set; }
    public double? Low { get; set; }
    public double? Last { get; set; }
    public double? Change { get; set; }
    public double? Settle { get; set; }
    public int? Volume { get; set; }
    public int? OpenInterest { get; set; }
}
```

And json Im trying to deserialize

```
{
"errors": {},

...

"data": [
        ["2014-06-13", 2.9959, 3.0302, 2.9853, 0838, null, 2.9943, 27331.0, 51662.0],
        ["2014-06-12", 2.9092, 3.0017, 2.908, null, 0.0838, 2.9948, 35321.0, 47057.0]]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude JSON properties that you are not interested in, simply leave those members off your class.  Json.Net will ignore them by default.

If a numeric or date value can be null in the JSON, then making it nullable in your class is exactly the right way to handle it.

If you don't know for sure what type to make `Error`, then `object` is OK.  You could also use `Dictionary<string, object>` here.  If you have an example of the `Error` data then you can make a proper class for it.

You can use a `JsonConverter` to get the array data into the object format you want.
Here is what the converter would look like:

```
public class DataListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Data);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken array = JToken.Load(reader);
        List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
        foreach (JArray data in array.Children<JArray>())
        {
            list.Add(new Data
            {
                Date = data[0].ToObject<DateTime>(),
                Open = data[1].ToObject<double?>(),
                High = data[2].ToObject<double?>(),
                Low = data[3].ToObject<double?>(),
                Last = data[4].ToObject<double?>(),
                Change = data[5].ToObject<double?>(),
                Settle = data[6].ToObject<double?>(),
                Volume = data[7].ToObject<int?>(),
                OpenInterest = data[8].ToObject<int?>()
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `Data` member in your `DataFormat` class:

```
class DataFormat
{
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Errors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DataListConverter))]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize as normal:

```
DataFormat df = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataFormat>(json);
```

Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""errors"": {},
            ""stuffToIgnore"" : ""foo bar"",
            ""data"": [
                    [""2014-06-13"", 2.9959, 3.0302, 2.9853, 0.0838, null, 2.9943, 27331.0, 51662.0],
                    [""2014-06-12"", 2.9092, 3.0017, 2.908, null, 0.0838, 2.9948, 35321.0, 47057.0]
            ]
        }";

        DataFormat df = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataFormat>(json);

        foreach (Data item in df.Data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Date: " + item.Date.ToShortDateString());
            Console.WriteLine("Open: " + item.Open);
            Console.WriteLine("High: " + item.High);
            Console.WriteLine("Low: " + item.Low);
            Console.WriteLine("Last: " + item.Last);
            Console.WriteLine("Change: " + item.Change);
            Console.WriteLine("Settle: " + item.Settle);
            Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + item.Volume);
            Console.WriteLine("OpenInterest: " + item.OpenInterest);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 6/13/2014
Open: 2.9959
High: 3.0302
Low: 2.9853
Last: 0.0838
Change:
Settle: 2.9943
Volume: 27331
OpenInterest: 51662

Date: 6/12/2014
Open: 2.9092
High: 3.0017
Low: 2.908
Last:
Change: 0.0838
Settle: 2.9948
Volume: 35321
OpenInterest: 47057
```

Comment: You almost made it too easy for me:) so much effort you put into your answer , that's exactly what I wanted thank you SO much!

Comment: nice one. didn't think of that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Data contains an array of arrays and not an array of objects.

```
class DataFormat
{
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Object Errors { get; set; }

    ...

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<List<object>> Data { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace List<object> with something where I will have right data types? Now I need to convert ´object{string}´ to ´DateTime´ and last two values into ´int´. The data array can have around 10k lines and Ill be working with multiple ´DataFormat´ objects with need for program to be as fast as possible so is it really the most efficient approach to this?

Comment: not that I know of. You could do a dirty solution and use `string.Replace` or regex to replace the inner array chars with object chars. something like `json.Replace("[\"", "{\"").Replace("],", "},");`

Comment: @Hnus you can use a `JsonConverter` to handle all the data conversion from the nested JSON arrays to your `List<Data>`.  I've added an answer to show how to do this.